# How to vlookup a combination of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

There are two tables

table1

```
team   member   income
blue            650
       Kate     500
       Niki     150
green           1100
       Kate     560
       Alison   600
```

---

table2

```
team   member   income
blue            'vlookup what formula should I put here ?
       Mike     'vlookup what formula should I put here ?
       Kate     'vlookup what formula should I put here ?
       Pete     'vlookup what formula should I put here ?
       Niki     'vlookup what formula should I put here ?
red             
       Stew     
       Mark           ............
       Alex
green  
       Kate
       Alison
```

---

I need to `vlookup` income from table1 and put in table2. The problem is that teams could have people with the same names . A record is uniquely identified by a team and a person name . How can i do this ?

Comment: Create an extra column containing the concatenation of the `team` and `member` column, and use that as your `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Because the result you are looking for is a number, you could use `SUMIFS` if on Excel 2007 or higher, or `SUMPRODUCT` for backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the layout shown you could try filling down this formula from `G2`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(ROW(A$2:A$7),ROW(A$2:A$7)/(A$2:A$7<>""),A$2:A$7)=LOOKUP("α",E$2:E2))*(B$2:B$7=F2)*C$2:C$7)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, you can create "helper" columns (which you can hide from view if needed):

[image]

Formulas:

- C3: `=IF(A3<>"",A3,C2)`
- D3: `=IF(B3<>"",B3,A3)`
- E3: `=C3&D3`

Similarly for columns J, K and L. Formula in M3: `=VLOOKUP($L3,$E$3:$F$14,2,FALSE)` - a regular `VLOOKUP`.